# URL redirect for Github raw file

Tags: java, authentication, github

A piece of existing Java code is broken. It is used to pull a static file from Github in raw format. For some reason, the URL is redirecting to another one with a random token at the end. I've specified HttpURLConnection to follow the redirection, but it seems not working. Here is the code:

```
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);

        URL urlClass = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection)urlClass.openConnection();

        String userpass = githubUserName + ":" + githubPassword;
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
        uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
        uc.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);  

        String fileContent = IOUtils.toString(uc.getInputStream());
```

The URL looks like this:
https://github.com/project/raw/master/filename.json
And after the redirection: https://github.com/raw/project/master/filename.json?token=somerandomlettershere

Interestingly the web browser can handle the redirection automatically and I can see the content there while the HttpURLConnection only returns 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

It was resolved by refactoring original code with Github Java API(https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core) in which way there is no need to access the file through the full URL, which led to the redirection issue, but rather providing the repository and the file name.